# LoadRunner what is wrong in the file operation part

Tags: file, loadrunner, operation

what am i doing wrong in the file operation part?? It is not creating the file. I have tried to put the file path in c drive as well as d drive, as well as 2 or 3 levels deep folder structure. but somehow the file is not getting created,

All the values that i am trying to put in the file are getting generated properly, as you can see i have used lr output message to print them out and check them.

```
include <stdio.h>
Action()
{

int i;
int imax;
int rand1;
char newVarName[500];
FILE* file_stream;
char * filename = "d:\\RouteDetails.txt";

web_set_sockets_option("SSL_VERSION", "2&3");

web_set_max_html_param_len("32000");


web_set_user("CTS.COM\\180937", 
    lr_unmask("5a2f9911b093f34e3f8ca40aa7064d"), 
    "transport.xyz.com:443");

lr_start_transaction("Launch");

web_url("transport.xyz.com", 
    "URL=https://transport.xyz.com/", 
    "Resource=0", 
    "RecContentType=text/html", 
    "Referer=", 
    "Snapshot=t3.inf", 
    "Mode=HTML", 
    EXTRARES, 
    "Url=/IMAGES/banner_bg.jpg", 
"Referer=https://transport.xyz.com/AssociateHome.aspx", ENDITEM, 
    LAST);

lr_end_transaction("Launch",LR_AUTO);

lr_think_time(3);

//**********************************************************************************************************

lr_start_transaction("searchSchedule");

web_reg_save_param_attrib(
    "ParamName=__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR",
    "TagName=input",
    "Extract=value",
    "Name=__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR",
    "Id=__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR",
    "Type=hidden",
    SEARCH_FILTERS,
    "IgnoreRedirections=No",
    "RequestUrl=*/SearchService.aspx*",
    LAST);
web_reg_save_param_attrib(
    "ParamName=__VIEWSTATE",
    "TagName=input",
    "Extract=value",
    "Name=__VIEWSTATE",
    "Id=__VIEWSTATE",
    "Type=hidden",
    SEARCH_FILTERS,
    "IgnoreRedirections=No",
    "RequestUrl=*/SearchService.aspx*",
    LAST);

web_reg_save_param_attrib(
    "ParamName=__EVENTVALIDATION",
    "TagName=input",
    "Extract=value",
    "Name=__EVENTVALIDATION",
    "Id=__EVENTVALIDATION",
    "Type=hidden",
    SEARCH_FILTERS,
    "IgnoreRedirections=No",
    "RequestUrl=*/SearchService.aspx*",
    LAST);


web_link("Search Schedule", 
    "Text=Search Schedule", 
    "Ordinal=1", 
    "Snapshot=t4.inf", 
    EXTRARES, 
    "Url=/WebResource.axd?
d=rcIyG2OcW8Jw0dVKAHKouB_qi7orHpXPRHHowC57SH37biy2txFUrKGEIgh8UEtEt0jJ-
7enVMK28-Wwz3rF2yEmfcDrzHeufqr4EpqK9Wo1&t=635418424260000000", ENDITEM, 
    "Url=/WebResource.axd?
d=hJgAHOWKmtlJ94s8P0gxTiQFUJpgzvWtwuVazXJ6sglaRQpqxuuT_S8s8fI7pyvl9Ckw2lX8f
1RaAi6-WLJEDtCkNXEaqZWMG0FmPRYC9oQ1&t=635418424260000000", ENDITEM, 
    "Url=/Images/home_icon.jpg", ENDITEM, 
    "Url=/IMAGES/ss_ord.gif", ENDITEM, 
    "Url=/IMAGES/ms_over.gif", ENDITEM, 
    "Url=/IMAGES/ts_ord.gif", ENDITEM, 
    "Url=/IMAGES/rls_ord.gif", ENDITEM, 
    "Url=/IMAGES/es_ord.gif", ENDITEM, 
    LAST);

lr_end_transaction("searchSchedule",LR_AUTO);

//**************************************************************************

lr_start_transaction("select boardingPoint");

web_url("GetBoardingPoints.aspx", 
    "URL=https://transport.xyz.com/GetBoardingPoints.aspx?
id=BoardingPoint_idMs&name=txtBoardingpointNameMs&city_id=1", 
    "Resource=0", 
    "RecContentType=text/html", 
    "Referer=", 
    "Snapshot=t5.inf", 
    "Mode=HTML", 
    LAST);

lr_end_transaction("select boardingPoint",LR_AUTO);

//**************************************************************************

lr_start_transaction("Search1");



web_reg_save_param_attrib(
    "ParamName=__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR",
    "TagName=input",
    "Extract=value",
    "Name=__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR",
    "Id=__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR",
    "Type=hidden",
    SEARCH_FILTERS,
    "IgnoreRedirections=No",
    "RequestUrl=*/SearchService.aspx*",
    LAST);
web_reg_save_param_attrib(
    "ParamName=__VIEWSTATE",
    "TagName=input",
    "Extract=value",
    "Name=__VIEWSTATE",
    "Id=__VIEWSTATE",
    "Type=hidden",
    SEARCH_FILTERS,
    "IgnoreRedirections=No",
    "RequestUrl=*/SearchService.aspx*",
    LAST);

web_reg_save_param_attrib(
    "ParamName=__EVENTVALIDATION",
    "TagName=input",
    "Extract=value",
    "Name=__EVENTVALIDATION",
    "Id=__EVENTVALIDATION",
    "Type=hidden",
    SEARCH_FILTERS,
    "IgnoreRedirections=No",
    "RequestUrl=*/SearchService.aspx*",
    LAST);



web_reg_save_param("RouteNo", "LB=<a href='javascript:OpenRouteMap(", 
"RB=,", LAST);           ////<a href='javascript:OpenRouteMap(

web_submit_data("SearchService.aspx",
    "Action=https://transport.xyz.com/SearchService.aspx",
    "Method=POST",
    "RecContentType=text/html",
    "Referer=https://transport.xyz.com/SearchService.aspx",
    "Snapshot=t6.inf",
    "Mode=HTML",
    ITEMDATA,
    "Name=__EVENTTARGET", "Value=", ENDITEM,
    "Name=__EVENTARGUMENT", "Value=", ENDITEM,
    "Name=__LASTFOCUS", "Value=", ENDITEM,
    "Name=__VIEWSTATE", "Value={__VIEWSTATE}", ENDITEM,
    "Name=__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR", "Value={__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR}", ENDITEM,
    "Name=__EVENTVALIDATION", "Value={__EVENTVALIDATION}", ENDITEM,
    "Name=ddlCityMs", "Value=1", ENDITEM,
    "Name=txtBoardingpointNameMs", "Value=Adyar Depot", ENDITEM,
    "Name=ddlMsEndLocation", "Value=135", ENDITEM,
    "Name=btnMsSearch", "Value=Search", ENDITEM,
    "Name=BoardingPoint_idMs", "Value=358", ENDITEM,
    "Name=BoardingPoint_idEs", "Value=", ENDITEM,
    EXTRARES,
    "URL=/IMAGES/ts_ord_over.gif", ENDITEM,
    LAST);

lr_end_transaction("Search1",LR_AUTO);
lr_think_time(3);

 //*************************************************************

lr_start_transaction("GotoTimeBasedSearchTab");

web_reg_save_param_attrib(
    "ParamName=__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR",
    "TagName=input",
    "Extract=value",
    "Name=__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR",
    "Id=__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR",
    "Type=hidden",
    SEARCH_FILTERS,
    "IgnoreRedirections=No",
    "RequestUrl=*/SearchService.aspx*",
    LAST);
web_reg_save_param_attrib(
    "ParamName=__VIEWSTATE",
    "TagName=input",
    "Extract=value",
    "Name=__VIEWSTATE",
    "Id=__VIEWSTATE",
    "Type=hidden",
    SEARCH_FILTERS,
    "IgnoreRedirections=No",
    "RequestUrl=*/SearchService.aspx*",
    LAST);

web_reg_save_param_attrib(
    "ParamName=__EVENTVALIDATION",
    "TagName=input",
    "Extract=value",
    "Name=__EVENTVALIDATION",
    "Id=__EVENTVALIDATION",
    "Type=hidden",
    SEARCH_FILTERS,
    "IgnoreRedirections=No",
    "RequestUrl=*/SearchService.aspx*",
    LAST);

web_submit_data("SearchService.aspx_2",
    "Action=https://transport.xyz.com/SearchService.aspx",
    "Method=POST",
    "RecContentType=text/html",
    "Referer=https://transport.xyz.com/SearchService.aspx",
    "Snapshot=t7.inf",
    "Mode=HTML",
    ITEMDATA,
    "Name=__EVENTTARGET", "Value=", ENDITEM,
    "Name=__EVENTARGUMENT", "Value=", ENDITEM,
    "Name=__LASTFOCUS", "Value=", ENDITEM,
    "Name=__VIEWSTATE", "Value={__VIEWSTATE}", ENDITEM,
    "Name=__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR", "Value={__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR}", ENDITEM,
    "Name=__EVENTVALIDATION", "Value={__EVENTVALIDATION}", ENDITEM,
    "Name=ddlCityMs", "Value=1", ENDITEM,
    "Name=txtBoardingpointNameMs", "Value=Adyar Depot", ENDITEM,
    "Name=ddlMsEndLocation", "Value=135", ENDITEM,
    "Name=BoardingPoint_idMs", "Value=358", ENDITEM,
    "Name=BoardingPoint_idEs", "Value=", ENDITEM,
    "Name=ibts.x", "Value=131", ENDITEM,
    "Name=ibts.y", "Value=10", ENDITEM,
    EXTRARES,
    "URL=/IMAGES/ms_ord.gif", ENDITEM,
    "URL=/IMAGES/ts_over.gif", ENDITEM,
    LAST);

web_reg_save_param_attrib(
    "ParamName=__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR",
    "TagName=input",
    "Extract=value",
    "Name=__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR",
    "Id=__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR",
    "Type=hidden",
    SEARCH_FILTERS,
    "IgnoreRedirections=No",
    "RequestUrl=*/SearchService.aspx*",
    LAST);
web_reg_save_param_attrib(
    "ParamName=__VIEWSTATE",
    "TagName=input",
    "Extract=value",
    "Name=__VIEWSTATE",
    "Id=__VIEWSTATE",
    "Type=hidden",
    SEARCH_FILTERS,
    "IgnoreRedirections=No",
    "RequestUrl=*/SearchService.aspx*",
    LAST);

web_reg_save_param_attrib(
    "ParamName=__EVENTVALIDATION",
    "TagName=input",
    "Extract=value",
    "Name=__EVENTVALIDATION",
    "Id=__EVENTVALIDATION",
    "Type=hidden",
    SEARCH_FILTERS,
    "IgnoreRedirections=No",
    "RequestUrl=*/SearchService.aspx*",
    LAST);

web_submit_data("SearchService.aspx_3",
    "Action=https://transport.xyz.com/SearchService.aspx?param_id=5",
    "Method=POST",
    "RecContentType=text/html",
    "Referer=https://transport.xyz.com/SearchService.aspx",
    "Snapshot=t8.inf",
    "Mode=HTML",
    ITEMDATA,
    "Name=__EVENTTARGET", "Value=ddlTsStartLocation", ENDITEM,
    "Name=__EVENTARGUMENT", "Value=", ENDITEM,
    "Name=__LASTFOCUS", "Value=", ENDITEM,
    "Name=__VIEWSTATE", "Value={__VIEWSTATE}", ENDITEM,
    "Name=__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR", "Value={__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR}", ENDITEM,
    "Name=__EVENTVALIDATION", "Value={__EVENTVALIDATION}", ENDITEM,
    "Name=ddlCityTs", "Value=1", ENDITEM,
    "Name=ddlTsStartLocation", "Value=135", ENDITEM,
    "Name=BoardingPoint_idMs", "Value=", ENDITEM,
    "Name=BoardingPoint_idEs", "Value=", ENDITEM,
    LAST);
lr_end_transaction("GotoTimeBasedSearchTab",LR_AUTO);

//********************

    lr_think_time(3);


//****************************

lr_start_transaction("Search_TimeBased");


web_reg_save_param("RouteDetail", "LB=<td align=\"left\">", "RB=</td", 
"ORD=ALL", LAST);

web_submit_data("SearchService.aspx_4",
    "Action=https://transport.xyz.com/SearchService.aspx?param_id=5",
    "Method=POST",
    "RecContentType=text/html",
    "Referer=https://transport.xyz.com/SearchService.aspx?param_id=5",
    "Snapshot=t9.inf",
    "Mode=HTML",
    ITEMDATA,
    "Name=__EVENTTARGET", "Value=", ENDITEM,
    "Name=__EVENTARGUMENT", "Value=", ENDITEM,
    "Name=__LASTFOCUS", "Value=", ENDITEM,
    "Name=__VIEWSTATE", "Value={__VIEWSTATE}", ENDITEM,
    "Name=__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR", "Value={__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR}", ENDITEM,
    "Name=__EVENTVALIDATION", "Value={__EVENTVALIDATION}", ENDITEM,
    "Name=ddlCityTs", "Value=1", ENDITEM,
    "Name=ddlTsStartLocation", "Value=135", ENDITEM,
    "Name=ddlTsTime", "Value=ALL", ENDITEM,
    "Name=btnTsList", "Value=Search", ENDITEM,
    "Name=BoardingPoint_idMs", "Value=", ENDITEM,
    "Name=BoardingPoint_idEs", "Value=", ENDITEM,
    LAST);

lr_end_transaction("Search_TimeBased",LR_AUTO); 

file_stream = fopen(filename, "w");

imax= atoi(lr_eval_string("{RouteDetail_count}"));
lr_output_message("count is %d", imax);

for(i=1;i<=imax;i++) {

    sprintf(newVarName, "{RouteDetail_%d}", i);
    lr_output_message("string is %s", newVarName);

    lr_save_string(lr_eval_string(newVarName), "stringtowrite");

    fprintf(file_stream,"%s,\n", lr_eval_string("{stringtowrite}"));

}

fclose(file_stream);

//****************************

lr_think_time(3);

lr_start_transaction("ClickRoute");

web_url("ShowRouteMap.aspx", 
    "URL=https://transport.xyz.com/ShowRouteMap.aspx?RouteNo={RouteNo}", 
    "Resource=0", 
    "RecContentType=text/html", 
    "Referer=", 
    "Snapshot=t10.inf", 
    "Mode=HTML", 
    LAST);

lr_end_transaction("ClickRoute",LR_AUTO);

lr_think_time(3);
//***************************

lr_start_transaction("GoHome1");

web_url("AssociateHome.aspx", 
    "URL=https://transport.xyz.com/AssociateHome.aspx", 
    "Resource=0", 
    "RecContentType=text/html", 
    "Referer=https://transport.xyz.com/SearchService.aspx?param_id=5", 
    "Snapshot=t11.inf", 
    "Mode=HTML", 
    LAST);

lr_end_transaction("GoHome1",LR_AUTO);

lr_think_time(3);
//*****************************
for (i=1; i<=5; i++){


lr_start_transaction("SMSShortCodeList");

web_reg_save_param("RandomLetter", "LB=aspx?Letter=", "RB=&", "ORD=ALL", 
LAST);                   //.aspx?Letter=A&

web_link("Short Code list", 
    "Text=Short Code list", 
    "Snapshot=t12.inf", 
    EXTRARES, 
    "Url=/IMAGES/BPHELP.bmp", ENDITEM, 
    LAST);

lr_end_transaction("SMSShortCodeList",LR_AUTO);

lr_think_time(3);

//***************************

lr_start_transaction("ClickALetter");


rand1 = (rand() % atoi(lr_eval_string("{RandomLetter_count}")) + 1);                 
//Find out a rand no between 1 and count
sprintf(newVarName, "{RandomLetter_%d}", rand1);
lr_output_message("newVarName is %s", lr_eval_string(newVarName));
lr_save_string(lr_eval_string(newVarName), "newRandLetter");


web_url("BoardingPtShortCodeDisplay.aspx", 
    "URL=https://transport.xyz.com/BoardingPtShortCodeDisplay.aspx?Letter=
{newRandLetter}&City=1", 
    "Resource=0", 
    "RecContentType=text/html", 
    "Referer=https://transport.xyz.com/BoardingPtShortCodeDisplay.aspx", 
    "Snapshot=t13.inf", 
    "Mode=HTML", 
    LAST);

lr_end_transaction("ClickALetter",LR_AUTO);

lr_think_time(3);

} 

//end For loop

//******************************

lr_start_transaction("GoHome2");

web_url("AssociateHome.aspx_2", 
    "URL=https://transport.xyz.com/AssociateHome.aspx", 
    "Resource=0", 
    "RecContentType=text/html", 
    "Referer=https://transport.xyz.com/BoardingPtShortCodeDisplay.aspx?
Letter=R&City=1", 
    "Snapshot=t14.inf", 
    "Mode=HTML", 
    LAST);

lr_end_transaction("GoHome2",LR_AUTO);

lr_think_time(3);
//**********************************************************************************************************

lr_start_transaction("Logout");

web_link("Logout", 
    "Text=Logout", 
    "Snapshot=t15.inf", 
    LAST);

lr_end_transaction("Logout",LR_AUTO);
//****************************

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Please explain why you are writing data out.   There is likely a better way to accomplish your goal.   With this model and multiple users you face a high likelihood of turning your local file system into a drag anchor as multiple users wait on an exclusive write handle.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not check if file_stream is null?

Include:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

Add at the beginning: `int err;`
Modify the way you open the file:

```
err = fopen_s(&file_stream, filename, "w"); 
if (err != 0)
{
    lr_output_message("Failed to open file (%s)",strerror(errno));
    lr_exit(LR_EXIT_VUSER, LR_FAIL);
}
```

This will show exactly the error.